# What is most performant way to iterate nested javascript objects and render inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, nested-loops

I would like to render this nested JS object inside React component into ol > li > ol > li format, and nested objects should be indented as per level.

JSON Sample data : https://jsfiddle.net/39o8nrpk/

It will be great help if I can get the solution to render this data in a performant way using JavaScript.

```
{
  "data": {
    "content": "Page Title",
    "url": "/",
    "categories": [
      {
        "href": "/",
        "name": "level 1",
        "category": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "href": "/",
        "name": "level 1",
        "category": [
          {
            "href": "/",
            "name": "level 2",
            "category": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "href": "/",
            "name": "level 2",
            "category": [{
                "href": "/",
                "name": "level 3"
              },
              {
                "href": "/",
                "name": "level 3"
              },
              {
                "href": "/",
                "name": "level 3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "href": "/",
            "name": "level 2",
            "category": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "href": "/",
            "name": "level2",
            "category": [{
                "href": "/",
                "name": "level3"
              },
              {
                "href": "/",
                "name": "level3"
              },
              {
                "href": "/",
                "name": "level3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: You are expected to try/research yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this approach.

```
{categories.map(({ name, href, category }) => {
      return (
        <ol className="level-1">
          <h4><a href={href}>{name}</a></h4>
          {category && category.map(({ name: nameL2, href: hrefL2, category: categoriesL2 }) => {
            return (
                <li>
                  <ul className="level-2"> 
                  <h4><a href={hrefL2} >{nameL2}</a></h4>
                    {categoriesL3 &&
                      categoriesL3.map(({ name: nameL3, href: hrefL3 }) => {
                        return (
                          <li className="level-3">
                            <a href={hrefL3}>{nameL3}</a>
                          </li>
                          )
                        );
                      })}
                  </ul>
                </li>
              )
          })}
        </ol>
      );
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you split your code in different components, each one at charge of rendering an specific categories level. Once you have this scenario, maybe you should **try to achieve it using recursion**, which in my opinion would be the best solution.

```
const CategoryLevel3 = ({ href, name}) => {
  return (
    <li className="level-3">
      <a href={href}>{name}</a>
    </li>
  );
};

const CategoryLevel2 = ({ name, href, category = [] }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <ul className="level-2">
        <h4>
          <a href={href}>{name}</a>
        </h4>
        {category.map(({ name, href }) => (
          <CategoryLevel3 href={href} name={name} key={name} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  );
};

const CategoryLevel1 = ({ name, href, category = [] }) => {
  return (
    <ol className="level-1" key={name}>
      <h4>
        <a href={href}>{name}</a>
      </h4>
      {category.map(({ name, href, category = [] }) => (
        <CategoryLevel2 name={name} href={href} category={category} key={name} />
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};

const Categories = ({ categories = [] }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {categories.map(({ name, href, category }) => (
        <CategoryLevel1 category={category} />
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```